# Copy few items from one list to another list of same type in c#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to copy items from one List to another List of same type.

```
List<MyClass> oldList=
newList.ConvertAll(x => new MyClass{
                                       id = x.id,
                                       name = x.name
                                   });
```

But I want to copy only few items of list.

For ex, I wanted to copy only id, name out of all the remaining items from newList to oldList.

But with my above code, all items are copied to oldList and all items in my oldList are replaced with items from newList.

How can I copy only few items here?

For ex:

myOldList :

```
id:1
name:abcd
age:15
```

newList:

```
id:3
name:xyz
age:25
```

Output:

```
id:3
name:xyz
age:15
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which list holds the values from which you want to copy? And what parameters are you using to select the specific items you want?

Comment: How do you decide which items you want to copy? Are there criteria? Are those criteria ambiguous?

Comment: @Santosh If you want some good answers, you need to answer some questions about what your results should look like as well as clarify your post.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i dont have any criteria, i wanted to copy to all the items of oldList. Lets say old list has 3 items of id,age,name and wanted to copy only 2 values from newList(id, name ) to oldList.

Comment: @Santosh Your explanations are ambiguous. Please provide an example of the information that is in the source list, and the information that you want to have in the result list based on the given source. If you can't do that, the question can't be answered.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited the Question with desired output

Comment: @Santosh Your example makes no sense.

Comment: I have both list(old and new) with values.But newList has some updated values.So copy only these updated values to oldList. Hope I am clear

Comment: Lets wait for the answer who understands this. Thanks

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's an odd case but it looks like OP wants to merge properties of objects in one list into another similar list

Comment: @Santosh You're example makes no sense as Ed said. I think we all understand you want to take updated values of an object in list 2 and apply those to the original item in list 1 and then make a new list containing these items, but your example has item from list 1 with id of 1 and the item from list 2 which supposedly has the updated value with an id of 3, how can you even relate these together?

Comment: @charliefox2 But he's unable or unwilling to say how he wants to merge them, so it should be closed as unclear/unanswerable

Comment: @EdPlunkett agreed that it's a poorly worded question.. I think if it were clarified further it might be useful to somebody

Comment: @charliefox2 I certainly agree that it would be. However at the rate OP is going, I don't think that kind of clarification is likely to be forthcoming.

Comment: wanted to take updated values of an object in list 2 and apply those to the original item in list 1(only 2 values).I dont want to make new list. oldlist should be updated

Comment: @Santosh see my answer (and the clarifying comment under it) and let us know if that works or if my assumptions are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a chat with OP I know OP wants to merge 2 lists with only partially defined fields into a complete list. I will call the starter lists `list1` and `list2` instead of `oldList` and `newList`

- list 1 has id **defined**, name undefined, age undefined
- list 2 has id undefined, name **defined**, age **defined**

So:

```
List<MyClass> newList =
    list1.Zip(list2, (first, second) =>
        new MyClass{id = first.id,name = second.name,age=second.age}).ToList();
```

However I truly recommend you use different classes. For example `list1` could be a `List<Integer>` and `list2` a `List<MySmallerClass>` containing only 2 fields.

(Also note in the original post you have really inverted newList with oldList.)

Comment: I dont have any condition

Comment: Ah. So by few items, you actually mean fewer fields of the class. Editing

Comment: Yes, fewer fields

Comment: Both of my lists are of same type and same number fields.

Comment: Then do you mean that perhaps you only set 2 properties/fields and keep 1 with a default value e.g. 0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171271/discussion-between-santosh-and-attersson).

Comment: This should be it.

Comment: This worked.Thanks much @Attersson in taking time to understand the question and give answer. Appreciate your efforts :) Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
oldList.Where(x => x.id == 1).Select(x => new MyClass{ /* items from x here*/}).ToList();
```

Comment: whats the where condition here?

Comment: The where is the location in which you add a filter to the items you want.

Comment: But i dont have any condition.

Comment: You said you only wanted a few items.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: i haved edited my question for output. So  i wanted to copy only id and name from newList to oldList

Comment: For the values your not populating, how do you know the values?

Comment: I have both list(old and new) with values.But newList has some updated values.So copy only these updated values to oldList. Hope I am clear

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're going for?

```
oldList = newList.Select((t, i) => new MyClass
    {
        id = t.id,
        name = t.name,
        age = oldList[i].age
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer assumes the lists are in the same order and of the same length. If either of those aren't the case, please clarify in your question.